# Need to calculate, how many people are work more than 3 month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate, how many people are working more than 3 months, 6 months, 9 months etc.

```
declare @actualDate nvarchar(10) = '2021-02-01'

select startWork
from sm.PeopleWorkPeriod
where endWork is null
```

Here I need to use dates from the query above. I don't know, how to do it:

```
select datediff(month, '2020/05/12', @actualDate) AS 'Total month'
```

[image]

**Example of what I need**

```
  Month        Number of people
| 3-6  month | 5                |
| 6-9  month | 7                |
| 9-12 month | 24               |
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is SSMS

Comment: Do you want to compare it with the current date?

Comment: With start of the month - '2021-02-01'

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use formatted text. If you need to insert records, you would use an `insert` statement? Check the documentation, have a go and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Why are you using `nvarchar` for a date? Use `date`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the number of months they have worked. Then use a `case` expression to group it (you didn't appear to take into account less then 3 months and greater than 12 months), then count the results.

```
declare @Test table (startWork date, endWork date);

declare @ActualDate date = '2021-02-01';

insert into @Test(startWork)
values
('1 nov 2020'),
('1 dec 2020');

select MonthGroup [Months], count(*) [Number of People]
from @Test--sm.PeopleWorkPeriod
-- Calculate months worked
cross apply (select datediff(month, startWork, @ActualDate)) X (Months)
-- Group them up as required
cross apply (select case when X.Months < 3 then '< 3' when X.Months < 6 then '3 - 6' when X.Months < 9 then '6 - 9' when X.Months < 12 then '9 - 12' else '> 12' end) Y (MonthGroup)
where endWork is null
group by MonthGroup;
```

Note: Don't ever use `nvarchar` to store a date (or datetime), use the correct datatype or else you create technical debt for the life of the project.

And please provide sample data as DDL+DML (like above) in future questions - you'll get an answer much faster if you don't expect us to type it all in.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question, you should be able to use this:

```
declare @actualDate nvarchar(10) = '2021-02-01';

select 'Less than 3 Months' as 'Months',count(*) as 'Employees'
from sm.PeopleWorkPeriod where endWork is null and 
datediff(month, startWork ,@actualDate)<3

union

select '3-6 Months' as 'Months',count(*) as 'Employees'
from sm.PeopleWorkPeriod where endWork is null and datediff(month, startWork , @actualDate)>=3 and 
datediff(month, startWork , @actualDate)<=6

union

select '6-9 Months' as 'Months',count(*) as 'Employees'
from sm.PeopleWorkPeriod where endWork is null and 
datediff(month, startWork , @actualDate)>=6 and 
datediff(month, startWork , @actualDate)<=9

union

select 'More than 9 Months' as 'Months',count(*) as 'Employees'
from sm.PeopleWorkPeriod where endWork is null and 
datediff(month, startWork , @actualDate)>9
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to show somehow, how many people work from 3 to 6 month, from 6 to 9 etc

Comment: @DimaKozyr then you need to show both sample data and expected results (as formatted text) so that we understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can add a where clause to end of query. If you need count of 3-6, 6-9 slots then you can get that though couple of self joins. I'll edit my answer to include these details.

Comment: @AmitMittal I added it in question below

Comment: @DimaKozyr i've updated my answer. It is yet another way of achieving the same thing.